# PayPal Payflow Pro Result 117: Failed merchant rule check

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, payflowpro

I am using PayPal's Payflow pro API on a test account and no matter what, it tells me the field is incorrect. I am using PHP. This is the string being sent to them:

> curl https://pilot-payflowpro.paypal.com -s --insecure -d PARTNER=PayPal -d PWD=XXXXXX -d VENDOR=XXXXXXX -d USER=XXXXXXX -d TENDER=C -d ACCT=5555555555554444 -d TRXTYPE=C -d EXPDATE=1221 -d AMT=1.00

And the response says:

```
RESULT=117&PNREF=A91A0D948350&RESPMSG=Failed merchant rule check
```

I have pass all correct information.Can you please help me for this?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

[Edit: You need TRXTYPE=S for charging a "Sale" -- and not C for sending a "Credit" to the card]

In https://manager.paypal.com , under Service Settings, select Fraud Protection, Test Setup, and Edit Standard Filters.

Clear all the boxes in the left-most column. Then click Deploy.

Fraud protection settings and other account-level changes will propagate and take effect within one hour.

This is documented in step 9 and 10 here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/payflow/test-hosted-pages/#set-up-paypal-manager , and on a Payflow test account applies to all test transactions (not just "Hosted Checkout Pages") by default.

Comment: I have set all configurations and still showing same error,even I had check from paypal portal and it's showing same error. Please see my below image:
https://ibb.co/hB5rkyT

Comment: You're passing TRXTYPE=C for non-referenced credit, i.e. trying to send money to the card, which your account is not enabled for. It should be TRXTYPE=S for Sale, charging money from the card.

Comment: Do you have idea regarding recurring feature CURL URL for paypal payflow pro account?